# refactor code from normal collections in angular 4 to use rxjs observables

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have code like this in components:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'file-upload',
})
export class FileUploadComponent  {
  files: Upload[];

  get canUpload() {
    return this.files.length > 0 && this.files.every((f) => f.state === FileUpLoadState.new && f.isValid);
  }

  get isUploading() {
    return this.files.length > 0 && this.files.some((f) => f.state === FileUpLoadState.uploading);
  }

  get activeFiles() {
    return this.files.filter((f) => f.state !== FileUpLoadState.success);
  }
```

I want to change the `files` member to a `BehaviouSubject`

```
  files: BehaviorSubject<FileToUpload[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
```

But I don't know hot to change the `canUpload`, `isUploading` etc. getters to use the observable, there is no `pipe` operator in rxjs 5.1.0 and upgrading is not an option for various reasons.

Do I need to subscribe in getter or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that there's no pipe operator, but before rxjs V6 it used extension methods, so `.map()` and `.filter()` should still do the trick. I didn't have a chance to work with Angular V4, but this should work:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'file-upload',
})
export class FileUploadComponent  {
  files$ = new BehaviorSubject([]);

  get canUpload$() {
    return this.files$.map(files => files.length > 0 && this.files.every((f) => f.state === FileUpLoadState.new && f.isValid));
  }

  get isUploading$() {
    return this.files$.map(files => files.length > 0 && this.files.some((f) => f.state === FileUpLoadState.uploading));
  }

  get activeFiles$() {
    return this.files$.filter(files => files.filter((f) => f.state !== FileUpLoadState.success));
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that getters also become observables. If you don't want getters to be observables, you probably can subscribe to them within getter:

```
get activeFiles() {
  let files;

  this.files$
      .filter(files => files.filter((f) => f.state !== FileUpLoadState.success))
      .subscribe(s => files = s);

  return files;
}
```

But I'd personally stick with first approach and subscribe to observables at the most late stage as possible.

Comment: thank you.  is there a problem with getters being observable?

Comment: I've never used observable as getters to be honest. Only problem I think of would be that it can trigger multiple subscriptions if you use all of these in component html. If that's the case, I'd turn them into class methods and call them from html. https://nitayneeman.com/posts/using-single-subscription-for-multiple-async-pipes-in-angular/ read this to understand how to share subscriptions. It could help in your case.

Comment: getter seems pretty awful.  is sharing the subscription the best way

Comment: If it works for your use case. I'd say yes. It will ensure that you subscribe to same data just once. It also can save you http calls. Also by letting async pipe do the subscription, you let angular manage subscription life cycle.

Comment: this is very helpful